# House and family in PA, job and apartment in MA

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax

I moved to MA for work, but my house and family remains in PA, as is most of my "stuff". I earn my income In MA and spend the week in a rented apartment in MA and come back to PA on weekends and holidays. I spend more than 183 days in MA as a result of this arrangement.

I'm confused as to where I should pay my taxes. My understanding is that both states are considering me a resident.

I think PA says my house, family and other ties are in PA so I'm a resident of PA, even though I spend less time there. And MA says I spend more than 183 days in MA so I'm a resident of MA. Thankfully it seems as though PA gives me a credit for my MA tax.

Am I correct? And also, can I assign my investment income to my spouse in PA so I pay the lower PA rate on this? These are generated out of joint savings and brokerage accounts.